# Sort bibliography with dalthesis.cls template

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

I call the dalthesis.cls template as the first line of my document

```
\documentclass[12pt]{dalthesis}
```

I call the references to be printed with:

```
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{aiaa}
\bibliography{References}
```

The printed bibliography is neither ordered by use or alphabetically. How may I achieve either?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: In section 2.6, entitled "Known Problems", of the user guide of the `aiaa` package, one finds the following charmingly frank passage: "The bibliographic style sheet `aiaa.bst` isn’t fully tested; and thus, you may need to fiddle with your .bbl file for your final copy." I wouldn't say that it's a good sign that the user guide provides absolutely no hint as to what "fiddling with the bbl file" should entail. The fact that `aiaa` package was last updated in 2004 [!] doesn't instill a lot of confidence either. Who is forcing you to employ this disaster-is-about-to-befall-us bibliographic style?

Comment: \bibliographystyle{acm} printed the bibliography in alphabetical order. Thank you Mico; this solves my problem.